# Repeated values in subreport. Too many pages

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report with 2 suppliers. I want to show items ordered by the 2 suppliers. For that I am using a subreport. 
For the 1st supplier there are 15 rows and second has 1.
But there are 2 many pages displayed. i.e. 92 pages. The values are repeated. Also a lot of empty pages are shown.

Please advise.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/i5n3z80m7c2itlt/Complex1.jrxml
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5qm5o9cz1yatfad/subcomplex.jrxml

Answer (score 0):

Mithnil,
In the complex1.jrxml query, how many rows are returned?  You put the subreport in the detail band, and without any report groups it will execute whatever is in the detail band for each row of the report query. Maybe you need to work on the query to only include one row per vendor.